# Possible to hide all details in NSIS installation progress page?

Tags: nsis

Using the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), I'm looking for a way to hide the details on the `MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES` page when having a setup with [Modern UI 2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html).

Currently an example of what I have is this:

[image]

And this would be what I want to achieve:

[image]

*(German only, sorry)*

As you see, there is no information about the individual file being copied as well as no way to show the details.

I've searched the documentation of Modern UI 2 but found no function to call to make these two controls (label and button) hidden.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to hide the file label and the details button that are being shown during a setup installation progress?

---

**Solved**

[With the help of Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402072/107625), I've managed to do what I want:

First, I put

```
ShowInstDetails nevershow
ShowUninstDetails nevershow
```

at the top of my NSI file. Next, I put

```
SetDetailsPrint none
```

inside at the beginning of the `Section "All files"` section, and I put

```
SetDetailsPrint none
```

inside at the beginning of the `Section "Uninstall"` section.

Both, my setup and my uninstaller now runs without showing details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ShowInstDetails nevershow`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/ShowInstDetails) + `SetDetailsPrint none`

```
ShowInstDetails nevershow

Section
SetDetailsPrint none
SectionEnd
```